# Output by given ID instead of number after using do() function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question about the do() function in dplyr.

Let's use the following example dataset:

```
set.seed(2409)
N=5
T=10
id<- rep(LETTERS[1:N],each=T)
time<-rep(1:T, times=N)
x<-runif(N*T,0,100)
y<-runif(N*T,0,100)
df<-data.frame(id,time,x,y); rm(N,T,time,id,x,y)
```

Now I want to run a function (i.e., correlation) for all IDs. For this I use group_by() and do() from the dplyr package.

```
library(dplyr)
cor <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(cors=cor(.[3:4]))
```

So far so good. I get the outputs using simply

```
cor$cors

[[1]]
            x           y
x  1.00000000 -0.09895815
y -0.09895815  1.00000000

[[2]]
           x          y
x  1.0000000 -0.4127625
y -0.4127625  1.0000000

[[3]]
           x          y
x  1.0000000 -0.5516935
y -0.5516935  1.0000000

[[4]]
          x         y
x  1.000000 -0.219373
y -0.219373  1.000000

[[5]]
           x          y
x  1.0000000 -0.1789057
y -0.1789057  1.0000000
```

But how can I get my outputs titled with the ID instead of being numbered? So what I want is:

```
[[A]]
            x           y
x  1.00000000 -0.09895815
y -0.09895815  1.00000000

[[B]]
           x          y
x  1.0000000 -0.4127625
y -0.4127625  1.0000000

[[C]]
           x          y
x  1.0000000 -0.5516935
y -0.5516935  1.0000000

[[D]]
          x         y
x  1.000000 -0.219373
y -0.219373  1.000000

[[E]]
           x          y
x  1.0000000 -0.1789057
y -0.1789057  1.0000000
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

cor <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(cors=cor(.[3:4]))

names(cor$cors) <- unique(cor$id)
```

Output:

```
$`A`
            x           y
x  1.00000000 -0.09895815
y -0.09895815  1.00000000

$B
           x          y
x  1.0000000 -0.4127625
y -0.4127625  1.0000000

$C
           x          y
x  1.0000000 -0.5516935
y -0.5516935  1.0000000

$D
          x         y
x  1.000000 -0.219373
y -0.219373  1.000000

$E
           x          y
x  1.0000000 -0.1789057
y -0.1789057  1.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)